# BeanCreationException when deploying Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am experiencing a BeanCreationException when trying to deploy my Spring Boot application. I am able to build and run the app on my local computer but when I try to run it on an EC2 ubuntu or in a docker container on my local machine I get the following error.

```
 Running com.horvath.ballparkpalapi.BallParkPalApiApplicationTests
23:05:49.428 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.horvath.ballparkpalapi.BallParkPalApiApplicationTests]: BallParkPalApiApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
23:05:49.682 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.horvath.ballparkpalapi.BallParkPalApiApplication for test class com.horvath.ballparkpalapi.BallParkPalApiApplicationTests

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)

2024-03-29T23:05:50.497Z  WARN 6992 --- [           main] ory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer :

Found multiple occurrences of org.json.JSONObject on the class path:

        jar:file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/google/android-json/0.0.20131108.vaadin1/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar!/org/json/JSONObject.class
        jar:file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20231013/json-20231013.jar!/org/json/JSONObject.class

You may wish to exclude one of them to ensure predictable runtime behavior

2024-03-29T23:05:50.541Z  INFO 6992 --- [           main] c.h.b.BallParkPalApiApplicationTests     : Starting BallParkPalApiApplicationTests using Java 17.0.10 with PID 6992 (started by ubuntu in /home/ubuntu/ball-park-pal-app/ball-park-pal-api)
2024-03-29T23:05:50.543Z  INFO 6992 --- [           main] c.h.b.BallParkPalApiApplicationTests     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-29T23:05:52.561Z  WARN 6992 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propsService' defined in file [/home/ubuntu/ball-park-pal-app/ball-park-pal-api/target/classes/com/horvath/ballparkpalapi/service/PropsService.class]: null
2024-03-29T23:05:52.583Z  INFO 6992 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-29T23:05:52.626Z ERROR 6992 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propsService' defined in file [/home/ubuntu/ball-park-pal-app/ball-park-pal-api/target/classes/com/horvath/ballparkpalapi/service/PropsService.class]: null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1318) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1442) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:552) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225) ~[spring-test-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152) ~[spring-test-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191) ~[spring-test-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:247) ~[spring-test-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163) ~[spring-test-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:383) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:197) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:88) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:278) ~[na:na]
        at com.horvath.ballparkpalapi.service.PropsService.<clinit>(PropsService.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
        ... 103 common frames omitted
```

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.horvath</groupId>
    <artifactId>ball-park-pal-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ball-park-pal-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this is my application test file

```
package com.horvath.ballparkpalapi;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class BallParkPalApiApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

On my local machine I am using:
java version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
maven-3.9.4

On my server I am using:
openjdk version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16
maven 3.6.3

I can't find anything that points to why it works on my local machine but no where else.

I have tried mvn clean package, I've deleted /target and .m2 and tried to redownload dependencies but nothing is working.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you read the stack trace you will see that you have an NullPointerExceptionn near the `PropsService` constructor. What happens there?

Comment: And presumably you are referring to a file that only exists on your machine and not in the container or cloud.

Comment: Oh wait I maybe found the answer while typing my response. PropService looks like this 

```
@Service
public class PropsService {
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final static File BATTER_PROPS_JSON_PATH = new File(System.getenv("BATTER_PROPS_JSON_PATH"));
    private final static File PITCHER_PROPS_JSON_PATH = new File(System.getenv("PITCHER_PROPS_JSON_PATH"));
```

Maybe the NullPointerException is coming from the bottom two variables.

Comment: Most likely. Btw, you're using Spring. Using System.getenv is usually sub optimal. Better give the `PropsService` a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class as a constructor argument. Then you can configure the values in the `application(-test).yaml`. This makes the application self contained which increases portability.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Once I defined the environment variables it started right up.

I will take a look at the annotation you suggested. Thank you very much for your help!